# Toggle the visibility of DIV's on click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have one million `div` elements.

I want to achieve the following functionality:

1. When I click a **vsibile** `div`, it disappears.
2. When I click a `div`, any `div` which was **invisible** reappears.

Example:

```
<div>1</div> <!-- Invisible div -->
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div> <!-- Currently visible. On click, div 1 becomes visible and this becomes invisible-->
... 1.000.000
```

Comment: May I ask why you have 1 million div elements?

Comment: @AndrewL. is a example, the idea is wiil be much.

Comment: your question is extremely vague - what is the beginning state, all shown or all hidden or only some shown? after page has loaded, what should the first click on a div do?, once you've clicked on a div, what should clicking on another div do?

Comment: Do you mean that clicking on a div should hide that div, and show any previously hidden div? So only one div will be hidden at any given time?

Comment: Cleaned up the question for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
prev = false;

document.querySelectorAll("#test div").forEach(function(a,i){
  a.index = i;
  a.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if (prev !== false) document.querySelectorAll("#test div")[prev].style.opacity = 1;
  this.style.opacity = 0;
  prev = this.index;
})});
```

```css
#test * {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want jQuery because it's not tagged, just JavaScript is tagged. Secondly this isn't what the OP wants. The OP wants to hide the previously clicked one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the lack of a jQuery tag there. Also, it does seem I misunderstood the question, but I may leave this here in case this is how the OP meant it.

Comment: There's no reason to overcomplicate things with jQuery when you can just use pure JS :)

Comment: @Miller Thank you for responding, I almost deleted this when I thought I may have misunderstood the question. :)